# "truncate log on checkpoint" option in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, transaction, log, checkpoint

Long story but our long term consultants (former employees) wrote a custom script years back (2006 or so) to interface with Tivoli Storage Manager and it appears to be checking for a SQL Server DB option named `truncate log on checkpoint`. Their claim is that it prevents the scripts from functioning and performing backups on the instance which is SQL 2012.

I feel that's complete BS since I cannot find any such option via `sp_configure` and backups are working everywhere but one instance. However I would like to remove a land mine, if that's what it is, and remove other obsolete elements. I do have them checking with the vendor but I don't have a high degree of confidence in anything that they say.

The research I did returned little more than it perhaps being an option for SQL 2000 or a Sybase option. Another claim was that it's called/used implicitly on later versions (2008 and up) when the recovery model is `SIMPLE` and there's no explicit option to turn it on or off.

Since the `TRUNCATE LOG` command is obsolete due to how transaction logs work these days, I think it's not an option that can even be queried at this point.

As I don't have any SQL Server 2000 instances about, I was hoping someone might recall this or could check it on one they have laying around. I've told them that it's nothing I can recommend. I was also hoping that someone can confirm this is obsolete.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can still see (atleast in SQL Server 2008R2) `trunc. log on chkpt.` using `sp_dboption`, and you can set the database option as well

[image]

[image]

In SQL Server 2012 and up, you will get a nice error

> Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 1
>   Could not find stored procedure 'sp_dboption'.

Its there lying for backward compatibility ONLY. In SQL Server 2000 and up, SQL Server has a concept of [**recovery model**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189275.aspx) that defines how the log truncation is honored e.g. In simple recovery - only a checkpoint will truncate the log where as in full recovery mode - only a log backup will truncate the log.

If you want to understand more about Transaction Log Management then refer to [Stairway to Transaction Log Management](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/73776/)

As s side note, SybaseASE even in newer version Sybase 15.7 has this option (As a matter of fact it has duplicate `trunc log on chkpt` and `trunc. log on chkpt.` the later is the one that SQL Server got in SQL 7.0 through SQL Server 2008R2 - seen in sp_dboption):

[image]

[image]

Comment: That pretty much as I thought. I didn't see sp_dboption in 2012 so I assume it's been removed. I did find the SP in 2008 and indeed the option is present in 2008. I'll happily take your word that it can't be changed. I don't want to change it even if it weren't obsolete. 
Thanks for confirming, as well as explaining the concepts so well.